# Marker is not showing up on google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am trying to show markers on google map in a web page.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script>
window.MY = {};
function test() {
    addMarker(new google.maps.LatLng(88.4, 22.5));
}

function addMarker(myLatlng) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        map: MY.map
    });
}
function initialize() {
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 4,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      };
      MY.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), myOptions);
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
          MY.map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude));
        });
      google.maps.event.addListener(MY.map, 'click', function(event) {
            addMarker(event.latLng);
          });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="googleMap" style="height:380px;"></div>
<button onclick="test()">test</button>
</body>

</html>
```

When I click on the map, marker shows up, but when I click on **test** button, marker doesn't show up for the specified location(88.4, 22.5). Can someone please explain me the behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The location [`google.maps.LatLng(88.4,22.5)` is above the arctic circle](http://jsfiddle.net/5h85wbk8/3/).  A latitude of 88.4 is very close to the north pole.

Perhaps you want [`google.maps.LatLng(22.5,-88.4)` (in the Gulf of Mexico)](http://jsfiddle.net/5h85wbk8/1/) or [`google.maps.LatLng(22.5,88.4)` (Kolkata, India)](http://jsfiddle.net/5h85wbk8/2/).

Comment: It was Kolkata. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your function test with

```
function test() {
var position = new google.maps.LatLng(88.4, 22.5)
addMarker(position);
MY.map.setCenter(position);
}
```

Your marker is falling outside map's viewport.